# How do I call a function on a PHP page from an JS Axios request

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, axios

I have a JS frontend where I make an Axios request to a BE php index page. The BE page has two functions getAllData() and getSortedData().

`getSortedData` needs 2 params passing in sortBy and sortType.

How do I call the relevant function and pass the params in?

I have tried this:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost/BE/index.php?f=getAllData',
  timeout: 4000,    // 4 seconds timeout          
 })
 .then(response => {
   return response.data;
})        
.catch(error => console.error('timeout exceeded'));
```

but that doesn't work and I need to pass the params in for the second function.

Here is my PHP index page that has the 2 methods in

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

 include_once 'GameListClass.php';
 include_once 'DataClass.php';
 include_once 'Classes/SortedDataClass.php';


 function getSortedData($sortby, $asc) {
   $json_games_list = getAllData();
   $sorted_game_list =  new SortedData();
   return print_r(json_encode($sorted_game_list->getSortedJSONData($json_games_list, $sortby, $asc)));
 }

 function getAllData() {
   $game_list = new GameList();    
   return peint_r(json_encode($game_list->getData()));
 }
```

### Edit

Is there a more elegant way than adding the function name and any params as a query string i.e

```
?f=getAllData,
```

Can I pass as params?

Example:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost/BE/index.php,
  params: {
    func: 'getAllData',
    sortBy: 'name'
 },
 timeout: 4000,    // 4 seconds timeout          
})
.then(response => {
   return response.data;
})        
.catch(error => console.error('timeout exceeded'));
```

Comment: Send it as a GET request instead, and on the PHP-side use `$_GET['f']` to decide which logic to use based on the passed in parameter.

Comment: that doesnt work for me,

Comment: What happens? Does it throw an error or just not behave as expected?

Comment: wrong it does work |I was trying to return it to check its value instead of print_r thanks

Comment: But is there a better way to pass the function call and params from the FE, feels a bit Jacky?

Comment: Ultimately you'll have to make a request to the back end. AJAX calls are perfectly normal way of doing it.

Comment: @gavin agreed but is there a more elegant way than adding  the functio name and any params as a query string i.e ?f=getAllData, can I pass as params example 
 axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost/BE/index.php,
  params: {
     func: 'getAllData',
     sortBy: 'name'
 },
  timeout: 4000,    // 4 seconds timeout          
 })
 .then(response => {
   return response.data;
})        
.catch(error => console.error('timeout exceeded'));

Comment: Just google how to write APIs in PHP. There are tons of frameworks available

Comment: @AyushGupta I dont want to use a frame work, I just want to know how I retreive the params passed from a js axios call in my php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this issue out by using params passed into React Component.

here is the React Component

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const dataConnector = (params) => (
  axios.post('http://localhost/BE/index.php', params)
    .then(response => response.data)
);

export default dataConnector;
```

I then call this via

```
    const params = {
      func,
      sortBy,
      sortType,
      filterBy,
    } = this.state

    const data = await dataConnector(params);
```